# back transformation of arcsine square root transformation

Tags: back-transformation

I have a LSD that has been produced from the transformation of percentage data. I want, if possible, to transform this number back in a % that can be plotted onto the graph with the percentages on it.

I have used the below formula in excel as recommended by the below website. However, it is not giving me a sensible answer.

```
=SIN(E2/180*PI())^2*100.
```

http://archive.bio.ed.ac.uk/jdeacon/statistics/tress4.html

any advice you could give me would be great.

Comment: What is LSD? What is E2?

Answer (score 3):

If $y = \arcsin(\sqrt{p})$ then $p=(\sin(y))^2$.

To convert a proportion to a percentage, multiply by 100.

Note that your original percentages have to be transformed to proportions before taking the arcsin-square-root.